# Flushdns and registerdns on multiple machine by powershell

Tags: powershell

Simple question but not able to find answer on google at the moment. My powershell version is 2. I want to flush and registerdns on multiple machines.

```
ipconfig /flushDns

ipconfig /registerdns
```

I can't use invoke command and psremoting is not enabled on machines.

Any advise how to flushdns & registerdns.

Comment: Ehh, enable psremoting on the machines? Otherwise, `psexec` might be the option

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy with `Invoke-wmimethod`

Create a list of your computers in a file named `servers.txt`, then create a script like this :

```
$listofservers = Get-Content .\servers.txt

foreach ($servers in $listofservers) {

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /flushdns") -ComputerName $servers

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns") -ComputerName $servers

}
```

By default you'll not get the output of the command, but you'll only get information if the command sucessfully ran on remote computer through this value :

```
ReturnValue
```

If this value equal to `0` that means the command was sucessfully executed on the remote server.

If you want to get the command output, you can achieve it but adding output redirection to txt file :

```
$listofservers = Get-Content .\servers.txt

foreach ($servers in $listofservers) {

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /flushdns > c:\flushdnsresult.txt") -ComputerName $servers

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList ("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns > c:\registerdnsresult.txt") -ComputerName $servers

}
```

Then you'll find a txt file on your remote server containing the result output of cmd command.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your powershell version from 2 (highly recommended - I have a powershell & dotnet update script to do this also) you can use:

```
# Get Windows servers on Domain
####################
$serversraw=Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*")}

# Filter responsive
####################
$serversup = $serversraw.name | where {Test-Connection $_ -quiet -count 1}

# Flush DNS & reregister
####################
Clear-DnsClientCache -cimsession $serversup
Register-DnsClientCache -cimsession $serversup
```